# Eloquent - Get single model when using morphMany in polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Contact` named model like this :

```php
class Contact extends Model
{
    public    $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'contact_id';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'tel', 'fax', 'email', 'mob', 'address'
    ];

    public function contactable ()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The above model can belong to some other model, for example `House` model like this:

```php
class House extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'house_id';

    public function contact ()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Contact', 'contactable');
    }
}
```

Each of `House` can only have one related `Contact`, but since `Contact` model can be related to other models, I have to define polymorphic relationships.

Now when I want to get a related `Contact` model of a specific `House` model, that is, return an array of `Contact` (*that only have one element*) while I want to get it as an simple object model; for example:

```php
public function edit (\App\House $house)
{
    $house = $house->load('contact');
    
    return $house;
    
    return view('admin/pages/house/house-edit', compact('house'));
}
```

The result is something like this:

```php
{
    "house_id": 6,
    "title": "testا",
    "header": "0f74e9aa891bcc6fb84aa744721d9692.jpg",
    "type": "sara",
    "creator": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-07-26 15:19:31",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-26 15:19:31",
    "contact": [
        {
            "contact_id": 1,
            "tel": "1",
            "fax": "2",
            "email": "3",
            "mob": null,
            "contactable_id": 6,
            "contactable_type": "App\\House"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to use `first()` method on a relation:

```php
public function contact ()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Contact', 'contactable')->first();
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()

What's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been checking to see if someone can give an answer but since no one is, I have a very wild guess that this has some chance of working:

```
public function contactRelation()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Contact', 'contactable');
}

public function contact()
{
    $this->load('contactRelation');

    return $this->contactRelation->first();
}
```

Basically what I think is you can't call the **first()** method on the morph relation, so maybe if you make the morph first and then try to call first on the result it might work.

Note that you no longer need `$house = $house->load('contact');` in your controller, just try to access the relation like this: `$house->contact();`.

Comment: thanks @TheFallen, according to your solution I added an accessor named `getContactAttribute` and add it to `$appends` property of Model that simplify access to contacts of model. now when I get a House model , related contact model is appended to it as a simple property.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to solve this without having to create two functions.

An example could be:

```
// House.php
public function contact()
{

    return Contact

        ::where('contactable_id', $this->id)

        ->where('contactable_type', 'App\\House')

        ->first();

}
```

Maybe you will have to change some names.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

The solution above can only be called like so:

`$house->contact()`

If you wish to use it the 'normal' way (`$house->contact->first()`) you should remove `->first()` at the end of the chain.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **morphOne** relationship

```
public function contact ()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Contact', 'contactable');
}
```